# Improve Regular Expression to match date time by quarters

Tags: .net, regex

I want to validate a string to match a date as`'dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm'` by quarters `:00`, `:15`, `:30`, `:45`

Example

```
12.03.2012 20:00
28.12.2014 20:15
31.09.2012 01:45
```

This Regular Expression is working for me

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).((20)\d\d) ([01][0-9]|2[0-4]):([01][05]|[4][5]|[3][0])?$
```

But, is this the best way to do it?

Please give some advise to improve it.

**After @Kobi great suggestions**

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.(0[1-9]|1[012])\.((20)[1-9][0-9]) ([01][0-9]|2[0-4]):([03]0|[14]5)?$
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you validating a date with regex instead of appropriate DateTime library?

Comment: It is an string that should contains a date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[01][05]|[4][5]|[3][0]`  may match `10` or `05`, you are looking for `[03]0|[14]5`.

`:(...)?` validates strings that end with `:`. You want something like `(:...)?` - the colon should be inside the parentheses.

Make sure to escape the dots: `\.` and not `.` - otherwise it matches all characters.

If this ends up on the .net engine, `\d` matches all Unicode digits, so you may prefer `[0-9]`.

I would also suggest the following code, which may prove much more robust (for example - it invalidates dates like 29.02.2013 vs 29.02.2012):

```
public bool IsValidDateAndHour(string input)
{
    DateTime date;
    bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
    return success && date.Minute % 15 == 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, I didn't really look at the rest of the expression, so this is a partial answer.